# Assigning a value to a variable using if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

Suppose i want to assign the variable named *involved* the value true if another variable, say the variable named p, has a value between 50 and 150. How do i do this?

I've tried the following:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int p = scan.nextInt();

    boolean involved; 

    if (p >= 50 && p <= 150) {
        involved = true; 
        System.out.println(included);
    }

}
```

However when i try this i get upp the error: variable p might not been initialized. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This works perfectly fine except that `included` is not a variable name. If it is a `String`, enclose it within double quotes otherwise edit your to reflect correct error message.

Comment: included is not defined in your code.

Comment: Do not forget imprort Scanner before your class starts: import java.util.Scanner; public class Main{...}

Comment: So aslong as i change the variable name to involved, it should be correct?

Comment: @Bradley He doesn't need to set a value for the boolean.

Comment: @Fosorf since you are using an undeclared variable, this code will never compile. Can you please show us the code you are using that gives you that error?

Comment: There is no need to use if loop, you can directly assign the condition to `involved` variable.

Comment: @GauravGupta if you don't keep the if, you change the functionality of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Change `System.out.println(included);` to `System.out.println(involved );` . Because "included" is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Either involved is written as included by mistake in your code, or you intended to put a string "included" in the sysout :

```
        boolean involved; 

        if (p >= 50 && p <= 150) {
            involved = true; 
            System.out.println(involved);
        }
```

or

```
boolean involved; 

if (p >= 50 && p <= 150) {
    involved = true; 
    System.out.println("included");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean involved;
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
int n = sc.nextInt();

if (n >= 50 && n <= 150) {
    involved = true;
} else {
    involved = false;
}
System.out.println(involved);
```

Comment: now you are changing the functionality. That might not be the goal.

Comment: It was the goal. Turns out i needed the else part as well. Thanks a lot, to you and everyone else! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it directly without an if-else:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int p = scan.nextInt();

boolean involved = (p >= 50 && p <= 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OKish except for the `println` statement, which tries to print a variable that does not exist.

Some point to improve:

- Scanner should be closed: we can use the so called `try-with-resources` statement: `try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in))`. This automatically closes the Scanner for you as soon as the `try` block is left. More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html
- As another user pointed out: instead of using if/else when conditionally assigning a variable we can use just use the the comparison as assignment.

Here the final code:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int p = scan.nextInt();
            boolean involved = (p >= 50 && p <= 150);
            System.out.println(involved);
        }
    }
```

BTW you should also check that the value the user inputs is really an int. If i now input the value "a" i will get a `InputMismatchException`. The easiest way is to catch that exception, provide an appropriate error message to the user and then exit the program.

Here's how I would do it:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int p;
            try {
                p = scan.nextInt();
            }catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Value not an integer");
                return;
            }
            boolean involved = (p >= 50 && p <= 150);
            System.out.println(involved);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is redundant. `(p >= 50 && p <= 150) ? true : false;` why not only `(p >= 50 && p <= 150);` ?

Comment: @RedCam, yes you are right, of course. Thanks for the hint. Updated my post.